# How to suppress a "Rare" ligature that pre-empts a "Common" ligature for the same character pair?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures, opentype

In several documents I'm creating with `LuaLaTeX` (using MacTeX2012 on a Mac that's running MacOS X 10.7.5), I primarily use the Adobe-issued font [Garamond Premier Pro](http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/landing/garamond/garamond.html) as the main text font. I use this font because it provides a slew of

- "Common" ligatures: These comprise not only the five TeX-standard f-ligatures, viz., `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl`, but also ligatures for `ft`, `fft`, `fb`, `ffb`, and a few more; and
- "Rare" (aka "Discretionary") ligatures: For this particular font, "rare" ligatures are available for the character pairs `ct`, `st`, `sp`, and `ft` (but not `fft`; see also below) in both upright and *italic* shapes, as well as for the character pairs `as`, `is`, `us`, `at`, `et`, `th` and a few more in the *italic* font shape only.

If just the "Common" ligature set is enabled (via the option `Ligatures=Common`), the `ft` and `fft` groups, in both upright and italic shapes, are typeset like this:

[image]

Just in case this matters, the Unicode character representations for these ligatures are `U+E18D` and `U+E187`, respectively. In the upright font shape, the "glyph id" numbers are `277` and `271` and the "character codes" are `57742` and `57735`, respectively. In the italic font shape, the Unicode character representations are the same, but the "glyph id" and "character code" numbers are 283 and 276, and 57864 and 57857, respectively.

However, if the "Rare" ligature set is enabled -- irrespective of whether the "Common" ligature set is enabled as well -- the `ft` and `fft` character groups are rendered as follows:

[image]

(*Aside*: For another rendering of the "rare"-style ft-ligature, check out the web page [Garamond type ft-ligature](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Garamond_type_ft-ligature.jpg).)

Not only does the "Rare"-style `ft` ligature look rather different from its "Common"-style counterpart, the `fft` ligature no longer exists at all: the `fft` character triple is now rendered as a plain "f" followed by the "Rare"-style `ft` ligature. For my purposes, the absence of a ligature for the `fft` character triple if "Rare" ligatures are enabled is rather unfortunate. The fact that the crossbars of the "f" and "ft" glyphs don't line up properly in the italic font shape is also rather problematic. Separately, I also prefer the look of the "Common"-style ft-ligature to that of its "Rare"-style counterpart, but that's only a secondary concern. (Incidentally, the Unicode character representation for the "Rare" ft-ligature is `U+E18E`. In the upright font shape, its "glyph id" and "character number" codes are 278 and 57742, resp.; in the italic font shape the latter two numbers are 283 and 57864, resp.)

*My question is*: Is there a way -- preferably using macros provided by the `fontspec` package -- to disable the "Rare"-style `ft` ligature globally in order to re-enable the "Common"-style `ft` ligature -- while still being able to use all other "Rare" ligatures as well as the "Common" ligatures?

Just for completeness, here's the code that generates the first example above:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common,
    ItalicFont={Garamond Premier Pro Italic}]
    {Garamond Premier Pro}
\begin{document}
ft fft \em ft fft
\end{document}
```

To generate the second example, replace the option `Ligatures=Common` with `Ligatures={Common,Rare}`.

Comment: One consideration is that typesetters historically eschew ligatures when they span components in a compound word, and the only English words I can think of that include "fft" ("offtrack", "offtake") are such...I think typesetters would use the "ff" ligature and liberate the "t" in both cases.  I know this is not an answer, but it may explain why some foundries don't bother with "fft"...?

Comment: I have never used `fontspec`, but would changing `{Common,Rare}` to `{Rare,Common}` have any effect?

Comment: @tohecz - A neat idea. Unfortunately, neither `{Rare,Common}` nor `{NoCommon,Rare,Common}` -- with the second possibility first deliberately disabling the so-called common ligatures and then re-enabling them *after* the "rare" ligatures have been enabled -- produce the desired result. :-(

Comment: @commonhare - I think your conjecture is correct. I should have mentioned, maybe, that some of my documents are either in German or mixed German/English. In German, there's definitely a need for an `fft` ligature, for words such as "gerafft" and "geschafft", to go along with the `ft` ligature. Of course, historically accurate typesetting of *old* German documents would call for the use of blackletter (e.g., "Fraktur") fonts...

Comment: small warning ... the unicode values cited here are in the "private use area", so don't expect that the shapes found at those locations in other fonts will necessarily be the same.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this heads-up. I mentioned the Unicode codes for the three ligatures just in case someone can find a solution that involves mapping one glyph into another by using the glyphs' Unicode character codes.

Comment: That is a font bug, the ligature lookups are ordered wrongly; the longer ligature lookups should precede the shorter ones (in the font) or they will not get applied. One possible way way to fix this is using an OpenType feature files, defining lookups that revert the unwanted ligature.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - Many thanks for providing this insight. If you wouldn't mind writing this up as an answer (preferably with an example of an applicable OpenType feature file), I'd very much appreciate it (and will upvote&accept it).

Comment: Ugh...ashamed at my Anglocentrism.

Comment: @Mico: Feature files can be very font specific (glyph names, OTL language systems used, order of lookups, etc.), without access to the font it will be stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - Thanks for this. I'll be more than happy to give credit even for partial answers. :-) For my purposes, I'd be perfectly content with a solution that transfers the unwanted ft ligature from the "Rare/Discretionary" group to the "Historic" ligature group (since I don't load the "Historic" ligature group!). Alternatively, if you could show how one might deactivate a certain glyph entirely, that would be great too. :-) If you can show how to do this for one OpenType font, e.g., `EB Garamond`, I think I'll be able how to do this for `Garamond Premier Pro`.

Comment: @Mico: OK, I added a (mostly untested) answer, HTH.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some thing like this using feature files should work:

First the feature file:

```
# scripts and languages, if the font use others they should be defined here too
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

# this undoes the effect of rare ligature on ft
feature liga {
  sub f_t.alt by f t;
} liga;

# move rare ft to historic ligatures
feature hlig {
  sub f t by f_t.alt;
} hlig;

# apply the regular ligature on ft and fft
feature liga {
  sub f f t by f_f_t;
  sub f t by f_t;
} liga;
```

The order of the above is important, this way regular “ft” and “fft” are used even with `Rare` ligatures, but not with `Historic`.

The glyph names should match those in the font with `f_t.alt` being the name of the unwanted “ft” ligature, and `f_t` & `f_f_t` being the names of the wanted ones.

The full feature file syntax is [documented](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html) by Adobe (but LuaTeX supports v1.6 f the syntax + FontForge extension, not the current one, so there are some differences).

Then it can be applied to the font by using `FeatureFile` fontspec option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common,Rare},FeatureFile=test.fea]{Garamond Premier Pro}
ft fft \em ft fft

\fontspec[Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic},FeatureFile=test.fea]{Garamond Premier Pro}
ft fft \em ft fft
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer certainly looks like it should work. Unfortunately, your conjecture that "uniXXXX (with XXXX being the hex Unicode value) might work" for the glyph id doesn't seem to apply, at least not for the font at hand (Garamond Premier Pro). Any other suggestions on how I can pass the correct glyph ids to the feature file? (I listed the unicode codes, character codes, and glyph ids in the body of the question.)

Comment: You need glyph names not ids, you can get the correct glyph names by opening the font in a font editor.

Comment: Success at last! I had to install `fontforge` (which, in turn, necessitated downloading and installing `Xcode` and `macports`...), and learned that the glyph names I need are `f_t`, `f_f_t`, and `f_t.alt`, respectively. I'll modify your code to include this information, just in case someone else ever has to undertake something similar. Incidentally, it turns out that it's not possible to assign `f_t.alt` to the "historic" ligature group as no such group is currently set up for this font...

Comment: @Mico: Even if there is no `hlig` feature in the font, adding one in the feature file will work (I tested that with another font and I know it works).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the relationship between the work of the feature file and the (prior) absence of an `hlig` feature for a given font. Maybe I got misled by yet another bug in the font `Garamond Premier Pro` when I concluded that it couldn't be done? (I've been aware of *at least* one more bug with this font: the italic font that's selected by default is the "Italic Semibold" variant, not the regular-weight variant.)

Answer (score 6):

My answer is essentially the same as that given by @svenper but it’s too long to be a comment and it may address Mico’s questions to svenper.

Perhaps I have a more recent version — version 2.000 — of Garamond Premier Pro than you, because with `Ligatures=Rare`, I get the rare “ft” and the common “fft” in both the upright and the italic. (Some foundries notify customers of updates or even send free updates; Adobe doesn’t, as if its reputation were enhanced by leaving lesser versions of its products to roam the wild.)

If you’re stuck with a defective version of the fonts and dislike their discretionary “ft” ligature (it does nothing for legibility), and if you want a convenient way to use all discretionary ligatures except for the “ft,” you can define `f\_t.alt` into oblivion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "mlig",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
      ["f_t.alt"] = "f_t",
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[
  Ligatures=Rare,% placing this before the new feature may be important; please test
  RawFeature=+mlig]% mlig = “Mico’s ligatures”
\begin{document}
ft fft ct sp st

\em ft fft as at ct et ij is ll sp st ta th us
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you want to restore the discretionary “ft” in one spot, simply use `{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-mlig}ft}`.

Please test this; it works for me, but then my copy of the fonts doesn’t show the original problem.

Another approach is to refrain from specifying `Ligatures=Rare`, and instead to define a new feature with only th discretionary ligatures you like. For example, suppose you like many of the discretionary ligatures but not “ct,” “sp,” and “st.” In that case, the common ligatures suffice for the upright fonts, but you need a new feature for the italics — let’s call it `ilig`, for “italic ligatures.”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "ilig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['a_s'] = { "a", "s" },
      ['a_t'] = { "a", "t" },
      ['e_t'] = { "e", "t" },
      ['i_j'] = { "i", "j" },
      ['i_s'] = { "i", "s" },
      ['l_l'] = { "l", "l" },
      ['t_a'] = { "t", "a" },
      ['t_h'] = { "t", "h" },
      ['u_s'] = { "u", "s" },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[
  ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+ilig}]
\begin{document}
ft fft ct sp st

\em ft fft as at ct et ij is ll sp st ta th us
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Finally, suppose you need to avoid `dlig` because of its effect on the f-ligatures, but you want the upright and italic “ct,” “sp,” and “st” ligatures, along with a selection of the discretionary italic ligatures.  You can simply proceed as above with `ilig`, and also add the discretionary ligatures found in both upright and italic to `liga`, which is already on by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "liga",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['c_t'] = { "c", "t" },
      ['s_p'] = { "s", "p" },
      ['s_t'] = { "s", "t" },
    },
  }
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "ilig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['a_s'] = { "a", "s" },
      ['a_t'] = { "a", "t" },
      ['e_t'] = { "e", "t" },
      ['i_j'] = { "i", "j" },
      ['i_s'] = { "i", "s" },
      ['l_l'] = { "l", "l" },
      ['t_a'] = { "t", "a" },
      ['t_h'] = { "t", "h" },
      ['u_s'] = { "u", "s" },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[
  ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+ilig}]
\begin{document}
Th γγ λλ ffi ffj ffl ft fft ct sp st

\em Th γγ λλ ffi ffj ffl ft fft as at ct et ij is ll sp st ta th us
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(Don’t try adding ligatures found only in the italic to `liga`. With my newer version of Garamond Premier Pro and an up-to-date TeX Live 2017, TeX seems forgiving, but I’ve played with typefaces in which TeX looked for, say, `l_l` in the upright font and, not finding it, produced “aegory” where I wrote “allegory.”)

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! The second solution, which you've dubbed the "ilig feature", works for me! It turns out that the version of the `Garamond Premier Pro` font family that's shipped with MacOS 10.13 "High Sierra" is still version 1.000, copyright 2005. (This information is courtesy of the FontForge utility.) I have no idea why Apple isn't shipping version 2.000 of this font (and probably all sorts of other fonts from Adobe...).

Comment: What I'll end up doing is to use your second solution (i.e., enable certain ligatures explicitly for italic and bold-italic text), along with a second font feature that enables the ct, sp, and st ligatures globally (i.e., enable these three ligatures for upright, italic, bold, *and* bold-italic text). For sure, much cheaper than to buy the up-to-date versions of the four font faces from Adobe! :-)

Comment: Thanks, Mico!  But there’s still no hope that I’ll ever catch up with egreg ;-)

Comment: Have a quick look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week : Who's in the top-left box at the moment?! :-)

Answer (score 4):

With recent versions of TeX Live feature files are deprecated.
With LuaLaTeX, another way is to change the glyph of the ligature.

```
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "norareft",
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            ["f_t.alt"] = "f_t",
        }
    }
}
```

And then add the fontspec option `RawFeature=+norareft`.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "norareft",
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            ["f_t.alt"] = "f_t",
        }
    }
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GaramondPremrPro}% 
        [RawFeature=+norareft,   % <-- the new feature
         Ligatures={Common,Rare},% enable both common and rare ligs        
         Extension     = .otf,
         ItalicFont    = GaramondPremrPro-It,
         BoldFont      = GaramondPremrPro-Smbd,
         BoldItalicFont= GaramondPremrPro-SmbdIt]

\begin{document}
ft fft \textit{ft fft}

\bfseries ft fft \textit{ft fft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! One small issue remains: How to (re)enable the "common" f_f_t ligature? With your present setup, the "rare" f_t ligature is indeed disabled (and thus the "common" f_t ligature is re-enabled); however the "common" f_f_t ligature does not seem to be re-enabled. How to enable it?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding an MWE that employs the `Garamond Premier Pro` font family, mostly because it provides both "common" and "rare" form of the "ft" ligature, as well as (at least in principle) the "common" form of the "fft" ligature. (Garamond Premier Pro is a system font on a MacOSX system.) As you can see, the "fft" ligature isn't (re)enabled. What to do? (If you have access to a MacOSX system, do run the MWE both with `Ligatures={Common,Rare}` and with `Ligatures={Common}`. You'll see that that the "common" "fft" ligature shows up once again.)

Comment: Thanks for the addition. With Garamond Premier Pro 2.061 (2.000 has [some issues](http://www.typophile.com/node/100270) so I would not mitigate this) and LuaLaTeX 1.0.4, it gives me proper `fft` ligatures. I suppose you could add an otherwise similar `type = "multiple"` feature and add rules like `["f_f_t"] = { "f_f", "t" },` and `["f_f_t"] = { "f", "f_t" },` but cannot test this as I don't have the problem.