# Pair kerning strategies in (pdf)LaTeX

Tags: microtype, kerning

I'm using the `microtype` package on `pdfLaTeX` and I'm wondering over the possibility to implement pair kerning, as opposed to single-character kerning, within the facilities provided by that package. If this is not contemplated in `microtype`, then I'd like to ask about different strategies to do so. `pdfLaTeX` compilation is not a strict constraint, although it is more convenient to me because then I could use the entire `microtype` facilities (not currently implemented for `XeLaTeX`).

My original motivation for this question comes from my using the `garamond` package and tuning the kerning for the character "T" in order for pairs such as "To" to display a better adjustment. On this font, the dot on top of the character "i" is singularly high over the stem and collides — or at best "it is almost there" — with the "T" when I use the tuned kerning. Nonetheless, this is just my original motivation, and my question has actually a more general scope.

Comment: Kerning is already defined between pairs of characters

Comment: @egreg: How can I select in `microtype` a different kerning for "T"+"i" from that for "T"+"o"?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `microtype`; the kerning pairs are defined in the font itself.

Comment: @egreg: So is there any possibility to do what I'm asking about? I mean, within or without `microtype`.

Comment: If you're willing to switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX, the pair kerning could be achieved by setting up a "feature file" (see Adobe's [OpenType Feature File Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html#6.b.i) for the reference guide on feature files) and (b) loading the feature file along with the font in question. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91512/5001 for an example.